# "Change" constructor in java?

Tags: java, class, constructor

Dumb question: can I change a constructor in Java to be similar to a String's constructor (for example)? Such as calling

```
class myclass{}
```

with

```
myclass sc =  "text";
```

Is this possible in any way?

Comment: I like the question, but note that in Java, class names should be `CamelCase`, so you might want to change `myclass` to `MyClass`.

Comment: When you assign a string literal to a variable, you're not calling a constructor. So ... no.

Comment: So there is a huge difference between `String a = "text";` and `String a = new String("text");`?

Comment: A significant difference, yes.

Comment: I havent done any java work for a while but does it have the same concept as C# where you can new an object and set properties (in java I guess these would just be fields) on it at the same time `MyClass myClass = new MyClass() { A = "a", B = "b" }`

Comment: @SystemUser There is a difference. If you call `new String` you are constructing a **new** string object from a string literal.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32020191/overriding-assignment-operator-in-java